# Elastica FOSElastica Symfony2 analyzers are not working

Tags: symfony, analyzer, elastica, foselasticabundle

I am on my way to figure out, how Elastica/FOSElastica is working. I got it running fine for like really simple search queries, where the product name exactly match my search string.

Since this is not a good way to search, I would have to add analyzers to perform better search results. But they are not working..

I tried to just copy&paste this example code (inserted my index/types of course) => http://obtao.com/blog/2013/10/configure-elasticsearch-on-an-efficient-way/#comment-16733

So, here is my question: How do I get my analyzers working? I guess, I have to apply them in my controller, but I am not entirely sure how I would do that...

This is my config

```
#app/config/config.yml

fos_elastica:
  clients:
    default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
  indexes:
    search:
      client: default
      settings:
        index:
          analysis:
            analyzer:
              custom_analyzer :
                type     :    custom
                tokenizer:    nGram
                filter   :    [stopwords, asciifolding ,lowercase, snowball, elision, worddelimiter]
              custom_search_analyzer :
                type     :    custom
                tokenizer:    standard
                filter   :    [stopwords, asciifolding ,lowercase, snowball, elision, worddelimiter]
              my_analyzer   _:
                  type: snowball
                  language: German
            tokenizer:
              nGram:
                type:     nGram
                min_gram: 2
                max_gram: 20
            filter:
              snowball:
                type:     snowball
                language: German
              elision:
                type:     elision
                articles: [l, m, t, qu, n, s, j, d]
              stopwords:
                type:      stop
                stopwords: [_german_]
                ignore_case : true
              worddelimiter :
                type:      word_delimiter
      types:
          article :
              mappings:
                    articleNumber: 
                    shortName:  [ boost: 6, analyzer : custom_analyzer, custom_search_analyzer, my_analyzer]
                    shortDescription:
                        index_analyzer : custom_analyzer
                        search_analyzer : custom_search_analyzer
                    longDescription: 
                        index_analyzer : custom_analyzer
                        search_analyzer : custom_search_analyzer
              persistence:
                  driver: orm
                  model: IndexBundle\Entity\Articles
                  finder: ~
                  provider: ~
                  listener: ~
```

This is my controller:

```
 $query = new \Elastica\Query\Match();

 $query->setFieldQuery(‘shortName’, $searchTerm);
 $query->setFieldFuzziness(‘shortName’, 0.7);
 $query->setFieldMinimumShouldMatch(‘shortName’, ’80%’);

 $boolQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Bool();
 $boolQuery->addMust($query);
 $baseQuery = $query;

 $filtered = new \Elastica\Query\Filtered($baseQuery);

 $query = \Elastica\Query::create($filtered);

 $articles = $finder->find($query);
```